# Add data to a specific range of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have an userform and i want to add to some cells data, every time i complete the textboxes with new data. I tried a for but it won't pass the first row.

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 19 To 33

Cells(i, 4) = TextBox1.Value
Cells(i, 5) = TextBox2.Value
Cells(i, 6) = TextBox3.Value
Cells(i, 7) = TextBox4.Value
Cells(i, 8) = TextBox5.Value

TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""
TextBox3.Value = ""
TextBox4.Value = ""
TextBox5.Value = ""

Next i

End Sub
```

This is part of the form im making:

[image]

If i use the coded provided by Variatus, it inserts the data in cells that are not in the range i need. I tried it before, but it happened to me also. Thats why i was trying a for and a loop or maybe a do/while to see the way around those cells range.

[image]

(The example i'm showing, is to insert into column D / row 19, the first TextBox1 value)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "but it won't pass the first row."?

Comment: Your code will fill range(D19:H19) with the data in your TextBoxes. Then it will delete the contents of these same TextBoxes and continue to fill the range D20:H33 with the empty strings now in your TextBoxes. I'd say the code works as designed but the design may not be what you had in mind.

Comment: @Variatus What i need is: the user will fill up the textboxes. Then after the button is pressed, add the data to the first row on that range. Then let the user add new data and repeat the process. Can´t make a way to let the user enter new data without the for repeating itself.

Comment: @bigben the first row its the first row that the data is inserted to in the range i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% I understand what you're trying to achieve, but if you are looking to simply add do the next row of data in column "D" you can use the below.

The function `LastRow` I have included will determine the last row that contains data in the specified sheet in the specified column - adding 1 to that figure in the calling subroutine will just continuously add data to the next available line. Hope this helps.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer

i = LastRow("Sheet1", "D") + 1

Cells(i, 4) = TextBox1.Value
Cells(i, 5) = TextBox2.Value
Cells(i, 6) = TextBox3.Value
Cells(i, 7) = TextBox4.Value
Cells(i, 8) = TextBox5.Value

TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""
TextBox3.Value = ""
TextBox4.Value = ""
TextBox5.Value = ""

End Sub


Function LastRow(wsheet As String, col As String) As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsheet)

LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

Comment: This worked fine. I had some merged cells, so i had to change those a bit, but works!

Answer (score 0):

The code below will do what you want. Each time it will write the contents of your 5 text boxes to a new row in the worksheet and then delete whatever was in the text boxes. If you want control over the number of times this action is repeated you need to create another procedure for that purpose.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Rt      As Long                     ' row to write to
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")               ' change point at the correct tab
        ' find the last used row in columns(4) and add 1
        Rt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
        Cells(Rt, 4) = TextBox1.Value
        Cells(Rt, 5) = TextBox2.Value
        Cells(Rt, 6) = TextBox3.Value
        Cells(Rt, 7) = TextBox4.Value
        Cells(Rt, 8) = TextBox5.Value
    End With
    
    TextBox1.Value = ""
    TextBox2.Value = ""
    TextBox3.Value = ""
    TextBox4.Value = ""
    TextBox5.Value = ""
End Sub
```

The same code can be written somewhat more efficiently using the syntax given below. There is no difference in the functionality. E&EO because I didn't test.)

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Target      As Range                ' first cell to write to
    Dim i           As Long                 ' loop counter: offset
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")               ' change point at the correct tab
        ' find the last used row in columns(4) and add 1
        Set Target = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)
    End With
    
    For i = 1 To 5
        With Me.Controls("TextBox" & i)
            Target.Offset(, i + 3).Value = .Value
            .Value = ""
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested the first code, but the problem i had with the `rows.count, 4` is that the data will be inserted on cells that are outside the range that i need. I tested multiple values but it won´t insert those values on the column i need, at least what i tried. I added a screenshot of the form im making on excel, so you can see what i mean.

Comment: It's the curse of merged cells. Had you mentioned them in your question I would have supplied a different answer. I point out that your "own" solution also gets the last used row in column 4 (column D). Having removed the offending merged cells you should now be free to deploy my answer. It has the better syntax.